# Неизвестный процесс тратит много ресурсов компа

Tags: windows, windows-10, процесс, asus

Играл в игру(60 фпс)
Ушёл на пару часов
Вернулся
Компьютер оказался выключен(живу один)
Не обратил внимания
Продолжил играть(6 фпс)

Пробовал обновлять драйвера, перезагрузку, антивирусы и сканеры реестра, встроенную программку от Asus. Все говорят, что проблем не обнаружено. Однако MyAsus заметила процесс без имени, который грузит 54% процессора. В диспетчере задач однако не показывается. Как можно узнать что это за процесс и удалить то, что его вызывает?

Comment: Это зависит от много чего, от того что забилась оперативная память до того что у вас в системе есть скритий майнер который работает по принципу если человек отошёл от пк больше чем 3 минуты нагружать систему на всю. Для начала попробуйте перезагрузить пк, если это не поможет проверьте пк на вируси

Comment: Выключен? Похоже на перегрев. Понагибай какими-нить стресстестами.

Comment: Поищите через [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).